# ARM Assembly code is not executing in Vitis IDE

Tags: sorting, assembly, x86, arm, armv7

So I am basically very new to Assembly in general. I was trying to write this simple code where I need to sort numbers in an ascending order from source data and rewrite it into destination data.
and whenever I run it, it shows: executables selected for download on to the following processors doesn't exist...

here is the code, maybe something wrong with it:

```
.global _start
_start:
    ldr r0, =Input_data   // load the input data into r0
    ldr r1, =Output_data  // load the output data into r1
    mov r2, #32  // word is 32

first_loop:
    ldr r3, =Input_data  // load the input data into r3
    ldr r4, [r3], #4   // load the 1st elem of input data into r4

    mov r5, r0  // move to the second loop

second_loop:
    ldr r6, [r1] // load the value of output data into r6
    cmp r4, r6 // compare the current element eith the value in output data
    ble skip_swap // if the current element is less than or equal, continue
    // swap the elements:
    str r6, [r1]
    str r4, [r1, #4]

skip_swap:
    // move to the next elem in output data
    add r1, r1, #4
    // decrement by one remaining elements (r2 was 32)
    subs r2, r2, #1
    // check if we have reached the end of input_data
    cmp r3, r0
    // if not, continue to the second loop
    bne second_loop

    // if the first loop counter is not zero, continue to the first loop
    subs r2, r2, #1
    bne first_loop

    // exit
    mov r7, #0x1
    svc 0  // software interrupt

.data
.align 4
Input_data: .word   2, 0, -7, -1, 3, 8, -4, 10
            .word   -9, -16, 15, 13, 1, 4, -3, 14
            .word   -8, -10, -15, 6, -13, -5, 9, 12
            .word   -11, -14, -6, 11, 5, 7, -2, -12

// should list the sorted integers of all 32 input data
// like if saying: .space 32
Output_data: .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
              .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
             .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
              .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

well, basically registers were all blank in Vitis IDE, even though I think it is supposed to be working..

Comment: Hi @Angelina, your code does not seem to be complete and cannot be assembled - for example, Input_data is being referenced, but is not present in your code. I would suggest to provide the complete code.

Comment: hey @Frant ! I slightly modified the code in the question